# How to make jar of a package and use that jar in other package in android

Tags: android, jar

I have a CoreApp project/apk in android. I have one more FeatureApp project. I want to use the jar file of CoreApp in FeatureApp by by javabuildpath -> add extrnal jar(of core app). Can anybody tell me how can i make jar file of CoreApp project. My package explorer looks like this. My Core App is not a library project.

[image]

Comment: Core app is not a library project.Its an apk that can run independently. I am writing one feature app that can add more feature to core app. So i need its jar so that i can use core app classes etc in feature app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that `CoreApp` works fine.just build and run it.

Then you can create jar to utilize its class files as mentioned below in 4 steps.

**Step 1 :**

Select all the packages which you want to export in jar file

[image]

**Step 2 :**

right click on it and select `Export`

[image]

**Step 3 :**

select export option `Jar file`

[image]

**Step 4 :**

Specify the destination location to save the jar file and simply move further

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow some steps like:

1: Create a android library project by selecting "is Library"
2. Create your target project which will be used this project or any empty android project
   and add your library project in this project (you can add library project from project
   properties).
3. When, you run your project, a jar file will be create in your library project's bin folder
4. Now, use created jar file in target application(add jar in libs folder).

Answer (score 0):

`Export --> Java --> JAR file -->` select the resources and code you need

```
   -->select the export destination ......
```